# Getting index of minimum double value within NSMutableArray

Tags: arrays, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I need to get the minimum value (and its index) among objects inside an NSMutable double array.

I get the minimum value correctly but I cannot get its index. A weird and very high number comes up. How can I retrieve the index?

```
double lowestvalue = 1.0;
double highestvalue = 100.0;
double n4 = 4.0;
double n2 = 2.0;
double n3 = 3.0;
double n1 = 10.0;

NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSNumber *num1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:n1];
NSNumber *num2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:n2];
NSNumber *num3 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:n3];
NSNumber *num4 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:n4];
NSNumber *numL = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:lowestvalue];
NSNumber *numH = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:highestvalue];

[arr1 addObject:num2];
[arr1 addObject:num3];
[arr1 addObject:num4];
[arr1 addObject:numL];
[arr1 addObject:num1];
[arr1 addObject:numH];

NSLog(@"arr1: %@",arr1);

NSNumber * min_ = [arr1 valueForKeyPath:@"@min.doubleValue"];
NSString *str1_ =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",min_];
NSInteger path1_ =[arr1 indexOfObject:str1_];
NSIndexPath *indepath1_ =[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:path1_ inSection:0];

NSLog(@"Min_ Value = %f and index_ = %ld",[min_ doubleValue], (long)indepath1_.row);


//Min_ Value = 1.000000 and index_ = 9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "weird" number is `NSNotFound`, which you will find is covered in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1417076-indexofobject) under the "Return Value" section.

The reason your object is not found is you have an array of `NSNumber *` references/objects, `valueForKeyPath` returns an `NSNumber *` which you store in `min_`, you then produce a *different* `NSString` object (effectively creating a "picture" of your `NSNumber` object) storing its reference in `str1`, and then ask `indexOfObject` if your *new* object of a *different type* is in your array – answer `NSNotFound`.

HTH

Comment: Got it. Many thanks for pointing it out. However how can I get the index of the minimum number?

Comment: @jeddi - lookup the object from the array, e.g. `[arr1 indexOfObject:min_]`

Comment: It gives me exactly the same issue (NSNotFound)

Comment: By the way, this is not the problem. My code works perfectly fine if the array is composed of strings, but it fails to return the index when the doubles are wrapped in NSNumbers. There must be a problem here: NSNumber *num1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:n1];

Comment: Or the problem is the formatting of the NSLog...... NSLog(@"Min_ Value = %f and index_ = %ld",[min_ doubleValue], (long)indepath1_.row); Any idea?

Comment: @jeddi – I copied your code from the question into a new empty app, changed the `indexOfObject:` to use `min_` and `path1_` is set to `3`. I was testing on macOS so didn't look at the `NSIndexPath` bit so maybe you have a second error there – you are using `indexPathForItem:` and then `row`, why not `indexPathForRow:`?